# Grouped recurrence by periods over a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with names, dates, and several categorical columns. Let's say

```
data <- data.table(name = c('Anne', 'Ben', 'Cal', 'Anne', 'Ben', 'Cal', 'Anne', 'Ben', 'Ben', 'Ben', 'Cal'),
               period = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3), 
               category = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","A","B","A","B","A"))
```

Which looks like this:

```
  name  period  category
  Anne       1         A
   Ben       1         A
   Cal       1         A
  Anne       1         B
   Ben       1         B
   Cal       1         B
  Anne       2         A
   Ben       2         B
   Ben       2         A
   Ben       3         A
   Cal       3         B
```

I want to compute, for each period, how many names were present in the past period, for every group of my categorical variables. The output should be as follows:

```
period  category  recurrence_count
    2         A                 2   # due to Anne and Ben being on A, period 1
    2         B                 1   # due to Ben being on B, period 1
    3         A                 1   # due to Ben being on A, period 2 
    3         B                 0   # no match from B, period 2
```

I am aware of the .I and .GRP operators in data.table, but I have no idea how to write the notion of 'next group' in the j entry of my statement. I imagine something like this might be a reasonable path, but I can't figure out the correct syntax:

```
data[, .(recurrence_count = length(intersect(name, name[last(.GRP)]))), by = .(category, period)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `data.table` alternative. For rows that *can* have a previous period (`period != 1`), create such a variable (`prev_period := period - 1`).

Join original data with a subset that has values for 'prev_period' (`data[data[!is.na(prev_period)]`). Join on 'category', 'period = prev_period' and 'name'.

In the resulting data set, for each 'period' and 'category' (`by = .(period = i.period, category)`), count the number of names from original data (`x.name`) that had a match with previous period (`length(na.omit(x.name))`).

```
data[period != 1, prev_period := period - 1]

data[data[!is.na(prev_period)], on = c("category", period = "prev_period", "name"),
     .(category, i.period, x.name)][
       , .(n = length(na.omit(x.name))), by = .(period = i.period, category)]

#    period category n
# 1:      2        A 2
# 2:      2        B 1
# 3:      3        B 1
# 4:      3        A 0
```

Comment: Thank you Hendrick, this was rather clever and also very memory-efficient!

Answer (score 4):

You can first summarize your data by category and period.

```
previous_period_names <- data[, .(names = list(name)), .(category, period)]

previous_period_names[, next_period := period + 1]
```

Join your summary with your original data.

```
data[previous_period_names, names := i.names, on = c('period==next_period')]
```

Now count how many names you see the name in the summarized names

```
data[, .(recurrence_count = sum(name %in% unlist(names))), by = .(period, category)]
```

Answer (score 1):

One option in `base R` is to `split` the 'data' by 'category', then loop over the `list` (`lapply`), use `Reduce` with `intersect` on the `split`ted 'name' by 'period' with `accumulate` as TRUE, get the `lengths` of the `list`, create a `data.frame` with the `unique` elements of 'period' and use `Map` to create the 'category' from the `names` of the `list` output, `rbind` the `list` of data.frame into a single dataset

```
library(data.table)
lst1 <- lapply(split(data, data$category), function(x) 
   data.frame(period = unique(x$period)[-1], 
   recurrence_count = lengths(Reduce(intersect, 
           split(x$name, x$period), accumulate = TRUE)[-1])))
rbindlist(Map(cbind, category = names(lst1), lst1))[
      order(period), .(period, category, recurrence_count)]
#     period category recurrence_count
#1:      2        A                2
#2:      2        B                1
#3:      3        A                1
#4:      3        B                0
```

---

Or using the same logic within `data.table`, grouped by 'category, do the `split` of 'name' by 'period' and apply the `Reduce` with `intersect`

```
setDT(data)[, .(period = unique(period), 
    recurrence_count = lengths(Reduce(intersect, 
    split(name, period), accumulate = TRUE))), .(category)][duplicated(category)]
#   category period recurrence_count
#1:        A      2                2
#2:        A      3                1
#3:        B      2                1
#4:        B      3                0
```

---

Or similar option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data %>% 
   group_by(category) %>% 
   summarise(reccurence_count = lengths(accumulate(split(name, period),
        intersect)), period = unique(period), .groups = 'drop' ) %>%  
   filter(duplicated(category))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  category reccurence_count period
#  <chr>               <int>  <int>
#1 A                       2      2
#2 A                       1      3
#3 B                       1      2
#4 B                       0      3
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(name = c("Anne", "Ben", "Cal", "Anne", "Ben", 
"Cal", "Anne", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Cal"), period = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), category = c("A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  {
    u <- split(name, period)
    data.table(
      period = unique(period)[-1],
      recurrence_count = lengths(
        Map(
          intersect,
          head(u, -1),
          tail(u, -1)
        )
      )
    )
  },
  category
]
```

gives

```
   category period recurrence_count
1:        A      2                2
2:        A      3                1
3:        B      2                1
4:        B      3                0
```